# ESXI and RAID 5 manipulation error, help needed

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, datastore

I have a ESXI server with a RAID5 datastore on an P410 controller. Lastly, I had a disk failed and when I tried to replace it, like an idiot I removed the wrong disk ! So my raid was now in status "FAILED"...

So, I replaced the disk correctly, booted with the P410 setup disk and re-enabled the logical drive. Now my raid is in state "Parity Initialization", not sure what it mean :

- Raid rebuilding ?
- Are my data safe ?
- Is it accessible while in this mode ?

Moreover, when I boot ESXI, the datastore is missing, my VMs are inaccessible. And if I try to re-add it with "Add storage" it warn me up that all data will be formatted.

What should I do ? Why my raid has changed of ID ?

Thank in advance for your help, my knowledge on ESXI are quite limited :(

Comment: It sounds to me like you've lost your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly it mean your array died, and now its recreating from stracth...

I hope you have a good backup to restore.

Comment: Unfortunatly it's an home server, I have no external data except for documents and photos. I can't afford 5tb of external backup for an home usage. Why does the raid take so long too rebuild if it's without any data ? It's at 64% after 14 hours.

Comment: @Karnalta some controller do it the long way, some other can build the array, take time too, but you can start to use your array while it do it.

Comment: Yes, effectively I probably can use it already as ESXi allow me to use it to create a new datastore. So, it mean I am waiting the parity initialization to complete with an hope for ESXi to recognize it again for nothing :(

Comment: @Karnalta yeah, with two disk not online the array is dead, sorry